# Cycles save as EXR image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, hdri, .exr

I'm using Blender Cycles to bake the rendering result into the texture. Yet, I've observed that many parts of the texture is over-saturated, but I could only save the resulting texture image into a png file. Note that my texture image is a 32 bit float, and my rendering setting is set for an EXR output. Yet, I still cannot save the resulting texture as an EXR file instead of PNG.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify. After rendering, when you press F3 over the rendered image, a dialog will pop up where you can choose EXR as the file type. Is the file type dropdown not there. The oversaturation seems to be a different issue, but you can read up on Filmic Blender Addon

Comment: No, if I change the saving name to .exr blender automatically changes it to .png

Comment: Are you changing only the file name? You have to choose file type from the dropdown menu in the bottom left of the window.

Comment: Mr Zak, oh didn't see that one. I could save that in exr format, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments:

The *filetype* in the **File Browser** context can't be changed in the filename area. It has to be set in the dropdown menu in the **Save As Image** section.

[image]